# Javascript event handler to execute after default behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

In Javascript, how can I attach an event handler so that it gets run after the default action?

```
<form target="_blank" action="submit.php" onsubmit="doThisAfterSubmit()">
    <input type="submit" onclick="doThisAfterSubmit()" />
</form>
```

Similar but insufficient Stack Overflow questions:

[javascript: Possible to add event handler that runs after the default behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14187585/863924)

[How to catch event after default action was performed in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/545841/863924)

I have read these but they are dealing with keystroke events solved with using a variation such as `keyup` over `keypress`. The only other solution I have seen is the `setTimeout()` method. I want to avoid using `setTimeout()` in favor of a more elegant solution if one exists.

My use case is that I want to remove the form from the DOM after the submit.

Comment: What do you mean by "after the default behaviour"? When the POST request has been sent? When the response has been received?

Comment: Once the submit has completed, another page is loaded, and your javascript is lost, so the answer is simple, you can't!

Comment: @adeneo Hint: look at the form's `target` attribute.

Comment: Give the form an ID (lets use `test`), `onclick="document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';"`. Form gets submitted, disappears.

Comment: `onsubmit="this.style.display = 'none';"` works perfectly. Perhaps the problem is in your `doThisAfterSubmit()` function?

Comment: @lonesomeday You get it. The form is posting to a new tab/window. I know how to hide a window and that is not what I am doing. I am removing it from the DOM.

Comment: I want the event handler to run as soon as the request has been sent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could perform the default action yourself, then do what you want, and then prevent the default action from running.

```
<form target="_blank" action="submit.php"
        onsubmit="this.submit(); doThisAfterSubmit(this); return false;">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Note: Calling `this.submit()` in "onsubmit" will not cause an infinite loop as you might think.

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/RV6Dv/)

**EDIT:** My original jsfiddle was only displaying text after the form submit. I tried it again, but changed it to remove the form like you want. That caused the form to no longer submit, even though `this.submit()` was called first. In that case, you can use `setTimeout()` to delay the removal of the form until the original thread is finished executing, like this:

```
function doThisAfterSubmit(form) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(form).remove();
    }, 0);
};
```

Now the form is submitted before it is removed.

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/RV6Dv/1/)

Comment: The first part of your answer got me excited, then having to use `setTimeout()` bummed me out. Then I tried your second fiddle and removed the `setTimeout()` and just ran `$(form).remove()` and it worked perfectly!

Comment: @ogc-nick - I wondered if it would work differently on different browsers, and apparently it does. It works without `setTimeout()` on Chrome 27 and IE 10, but not on Firefox 27.

Comment: Ah very interesting. Yes I was testing it in chrome. My target browser is Firefox unfortunately, I just didn't expect FF and Chrome to differ on the point. I still like the approach though.

Comment: What about for events that are not cancellable?

Comment: @LorenShqipognja - What kind of event are you thinking of?

Comment: @JohnS DOMNodeRemoved for example (although deprecated still used for older browsers that do not support the observer pattern). In this scenario the node is not actually removed until the event has finished executing and bubbling, and I cannot seem to find a way to have a callback execute after it is completed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use event bubbling instead:

```
<div onclick="this.remove();">
  <form target="_blank" action="submit.php" onsubmit="alert('submitted);">
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```